# Font Format in Form Errors

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just implemented a jQuery script into my website to create labels inside my input fields. I am using Google Web Fonts to display the fonts on my site, and sometimes when the site is refreshed the font format in the form area only gets lost in the rendering of the CSS file.

The website is http://www.cashhomenetwork.com

You will have to refresh the page a few times to see the form format error. Please let me know if you have any solutions.

I cannot post images since I just opened this account, and my reputation is under 10. Please let me know what information you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use font-face declaration in css to display your fonts:

something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "BPG Mrgvlovani Caps 2010";
    src: url("fonts/bpg_mrgvlovani_caps.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

you will have to generate from your font .eot files for IE. you can easily do it using the online tool:

http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting post from Paul Irish :

http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Best way to use font-face :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Graublau Web';
src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
src: local('☺'),
     url('GraublauWeb.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

Then all you need is http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to generate eot, woff and ttf files from your original font file.